# Can I get pipeline parameters in Synapse Studio Notebook dynamically without predefining parameter names in parameter cell?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

In the Pipeline that triggers the Notebook, I'm passing some base parameters in, as below.
[image]

Right now, all the materials I read instructed me to declare variables inside the Notebook parameter cell with the same names, as below.
[image]

Is there a way that I can get the Pipeline parameters dynamically without pre-defining the variables? (Similar mechanism with `sys.argv`, in which a list of args are returned without the need of predefined variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To be able to pass parameters, you should have them declared in the synapse notebooks so that the values can be received and used as per requirement.
- The closest functionality similar to `sys.argv` you can get is to just declare one parameter in the parameter cell.

[image]

- Now, concatenate all the values separated by a delimiter like `space` or `,`. So that, you can just use split and use the values same as `sys.argv`. So, instead of creating new parameters each time, you can just concatenate the value to this parameter itself.

```
@{pipeline().parameters.a} @{pipeline().parameters.b} @{pipeline().parameters.c}
```

[image]

- When I run this, the values would be passed as shown below. You can use split on args variable and then use the values accordingly.

[image]